# How to schedule a removeEventListener inside an addEventListener?

Tags: dom-events, purescript

I'm trying to define an event listener that can trigger its own removal.

The usual way is to define the listener, then use the reference when calling addEventListener. And using the same reference when calling removeEventListener. As Purescript is a strict language, it seems I can't do that because I can't refer to the listener I'm defining.

```
import Web.Event.EventTarget
do
  listener <- eventListever (\event -> do
                 somethingUsefulWith event
                 _ <- removeEventListener evType listener' false target
                 pure unit
                 )
  addEventListener evType listener false target
```

I expect listener' to be listener but, as it is impossible, I don't know if there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current solution would be to use a `Ref`.

```
import Effect.Ref as Ref

example = do
  listenerRef <- Ref.new Nothing
  listener <- eventListener \event -> do
    Ref.read listenerRef >>= traverse_ \listener -> do
      removeEventListener evType listener false target
  Ref.write (Just listener) listenerRef
  addEventListener evType listener false target
```